# Sorting the element in a PDB text file

Tags: sorting

I am a new user of *Mathematica* and currently using version 9. I want to rearrange the element of one PDB text file with respect to another PDB text file. Suppose I have a PDB file like this:

```
HETATM    1   C1 UNK     0      14.406  17.458  -0.592  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM    2   H1 UNK     0      15.490  17.698  -0.832  1.00  0.00           H  
HETATM    3   C2 UNK     0      13.604  17.656  -1.892  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM    4   H2 UNK     0      14.009  16.956  -2.694  1.00  0.00           H  
HETATM    5   H3 UNK     0      13.710  18.738  -2.241  1.00  0.00           H  
HETATM    6   H4 UNK     0      12.506  17.420  -1.717  1.00  0.00           H  
HETATM    7   C3 UNK     0      13.987  18.450   0.505  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM    8   O1 UNK     0      14.203  19.812  -0.103  1.00  0.00           O  
HETATM    9   H5 UNK     0      12.905  18.324   0.828  1.00  0.00           H  
HETATM   10   H6 UNK     0      14.669  18.317   1.409  1.00  0.00           H
```

Now I want to rearrange the above file with respect to the following file:

```
HETATM    1   H2 UNK     0      14.009  16.956  -2.694  1.00  0.00           H  
HETATM    2   H1 UNK     0      15.490  17.698  -0.832  1.00  0.00           H  
HETATM    3   C3 UNK     0      13.987  18.450   0.505  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM    4   H6 UNK     0      14.669  18.317   1.409  1.00  0.00           H  
HETATM    5   H3 UNK     0      13.710  18.738  -2.241  1.00  0.00           H    
HETATM    6   O1 UNK     0      14.203  19.812  -0.103  1.00  0.00           O       
HETATM    7   C2 UNK     0      13.604  17.656  -1.892  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM    8   C1 UNK     0      14.406  17.458  -0.592  1.00  0.00           C    
HETATM    9   H5 UNK     0      12.905  18.324   0.828  1.00  0.00           H  
HETATM   10   H4 UNK     0      12.506  17.420  -1.717  1.00  0.00           H
```

How can I do it? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You have to be a more precise about the type of  rearrangement you want. The examples you provide leave us guessing what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you wish to renumber your lines sequentially or not.  I also don't know if lines are certain to be unique.  I will have to make assumptions.

You first need to read your tables into *Mathematica*.  This can be done with `Import`, though you should also look at `ReadList` for maximum performance.

I will call the tables `t1` and `t2`:

```
{t1, t2} = Import /@ {"file1.txt", "file2.txt"};
```

A quite general approach is to create a look-up table with the position of each element in `t2`.  I don't know if you will need to match on all fields after the third one, or if it is sufficient to match on the third field (column) only.  I shall assume all fields after the third, and use the `Part` specification `3 ;;`.  This look-up table is in the form of replacement rules, optimized with `Dispatch`:

```
rls = Dispatch @ MapIndexed[Rule, t2[[All, 3 ;;]]];
```

We can apply it like this (note matching `Part` spec; `Grid` is only for display):

```
SortBy[t1, #[[3 ;;]] /. rls &] // Grid
```

$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
 \text{HETATM} & 4 & \text{H2} & \text{UNK} & 0 & 14.009 & 16.956 & -2.694 & 1. & 0. & H \\
 \text{HETATM} & 2 & \text{H1} & \text{UNK} & 0 & 15.49 & 17.698 & -0.832 & 1. & 0. & H \\
 \text{HETATM} & 7 & \text{C3} & \text{UNK} & 0 & 13.987 & 18.45 & 0.505 & 1. & 0. & C \\
 \text{HETATM} & 10 & \text{H6} & \text{UNK} & 0 & 14.669 & 18.317 & 1.409 & 1. & 0. & H \\
 \text{HETATM} & 5 & \text{H3} & \text{UNK} & 0 & 13.71 & 18.738 & -2.241 & 1. & 0. & H \\
 \text{HETATM} & 8 & \text{O1} & \text{UNK} & 0 & 14.203 & 19.812 & -0.103 & 1. & 0. & O \\
 \text{HETATM} & 3 & \text{C2} & \text{UNK} & 0 & 13.604 & 17.656 & -1.892 & 1. & 0. & C \\
 \text{HETATM} & 1 & \text{C1} & \text{UNK} & 0 & 14.406 & 17.458 & -0.592 & 1. & 0. & C \\
 \text{HETATM} & 9 & \text{H5} & \text{UNK} & 0 & 12.905 & 18.324 & 0.828 & 1. & 0. & H \\
 \text{HETATM} & 6 & \text{H4} & \text{UNK} & 0 & 12.506 & 17.42 & -1.717 & 1. & 0. & H
\end{array}
$

If you wish to fix columns one and two and only change the following columns you could do that like this:

```
t3 = t1;

t3[[All, 3 ;;]] = SortBy[t3[[All, 3 ;;]], # /. rls &];

t3 // Grid
```

Another method that is fast, but perhaps hard to follow is this:

```
ords = Ordering @ #[[All, 3 ;;]] & /@ {t1, t2};

t1[[ #[[Ordering @ #2]] ]] & @@ ords // Grid
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I want to fix first two column. How will i save the edited file into PDB format?

Comment: @Sushanta support for that format is described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/PDB.html).  What have you tried and where are you running into trouble?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard the lines are certain to be unique, since these files represent molecular structures, and one cannot meaningfully have two identical atoms on top of each other.

Comment: @Oleksandr Good to know, but probably a bit late to be helpful this time. :^)